# Error comunicaion de API Angular-PHP

Tags: php, angular, api

noches, dias, vengo con un problema que me esta haciendo arrancarme el cabello, veran estoy implementando una api de php en Angular, el Api esta 100% funcional, pues la probe por separado, el problema es una comunicacion entre Angular y PHP

Mi primer problema fue CORS que lo supere con este pedazo de codoigo como un proxy.config.json

```
{
"/Alumnos/*":{
    "target":"http://localhost:4000",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

El segundo problema es que a la hora de enviar un formulario me da el error 500..!!
Los datos del formulario ya los recibo bien

[image: error]

Esto ocurre en mi componente agregar(add) en la funcion que abre el submit del formulario

```
add(){
console.log(this.alumno);
this.studentService.add(this.alumno).subscribe(resultado => {
  if(!resultado['insert']){
    alert("Error backend");
  }else{
    this.router.navigate(['/Alumno']);
  }
})
}
```

Esto manda a llamar a la siguiente funcion de mi servicio

```
  add(alumno : any): Observable<any>{
   return this.http.post("http://localhost/Alumnos/add.php", JSON.stringify(alumno));
  }
```

Ahora, la ruta que se ve ahi "http://localhost/Alumnos/add.php" es este codigo

```
<?php

  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");

  require_once "models/alumno.php";

  $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 

  if($datos != NULL){

     if($alumno->add($datos->nombre,$datos->grado,$datos->grupo)){
        echo json_encode(['insert' => TRUE]);
   }else{
        echo json_encode(['insert' => FALSE]);
   }

   }else{
     echo json_encode(['insert' => FALSE]);
   }
```

El cual manda error si no hay datos llegando y lo hace bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero según el error ya al usarlo en angular la ruta no existe, ya no se que mas hacer, espero alguien vea algo que yo no, gracias..!!

Comment: No veo donde instancias el modelo. aparece la variable $alumno directamente. El error que muestras no es de angular, parece que el que está arrojando error 500 es PHP.
Intenta hacer una petición con angular a cualquier API gratuita.
También puedes intentar hacer la petición con postman y ver si también recibes un error 500 o no.

Answer (score 0):

**Internar server Error 500** se debe a un error en el código del api
aquí tienes dos problemas diferentes.

1. la respuesta que obtienes en el navegador  `{"insert":false}` se debe aquí estas utilizando el método `GET`. y angular al estar enviado informacion por el body esta utilizando el método `POST`

Dicho esto: Debes validar el método método del ruquest

```html
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"){
  echo json_encode([ "status" : "error" ,"mensaje": "INVALID METHOD" ]);
}
```

2. Verifica que la respuesta este llegando al documento `.php`

Te recomiendo comentar todo el código que tengas  y  en la parte superior  imprimir un json

```html
<?php

echo json_encode(["status":"solicutiud recibida"]);

/*
 Aqui todo tu codigo

*/

?>
```

imprimi la respuesta con `console.log(response)` en la parte de **Angular**

**Consejo que no has pedido**

Cuando Angular, Vue , React  o cualquier otro `framework` de `JavaScript`  hacen  `http request` por cualquier método (POST,GET,PATCH,PUT,DELETE)  siempre hace un `pre-fly` a `OPTIONS` (una solicitud de prueba) para saber los métodos permitidos en esa dirección.

Dicho esto : El problema de `CORS` no esta en el cliente (**ANGULAR**) esta en el Servidor (**PHP**) para solucionar este problema.

Utiliza este código

```html
#asi evitamos que vue,angular,React y cualquier otro de errores de CORS
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    die();
}
```